# Getting error MSB406 "TypeScript.Tasks.CheckFileSystemCaseSensitive" in Windows Powershell but the same build works in VS Powershell

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, powershell, msbuild

While trying to build a newly setup project using `npm run build`, I am facing the below mentioned error in Powershell on Windows, however, it runs fine inside the Visual Studio integrated Powershell.

Error:

> C:..\src\packages\Microsoft.Portal.Tools.5.0.303.3330\build\TypeScript\tools\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(219,5): error MSB406 2: The "TypeScript.Tasks.CheckFileSystemCaseSensitive" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:..\src\packages\Microsoft.Portal.Tools.5.0.303.3330\build\TypeScript\build..\tools\net45\TypeScript.Tasks.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask[C:..\src\Default\Extension\Extension.csproj]

Comment: Can you update OP with version of VS , TypeScript and PS you are using?

Comment: @CodeRunner VS Version:16.6.0, Typescript Version: 3.9.3, Powershell Version: 5.1.19041.1

Answer (score 1):

> Getting error MSB406 “TypeScript.Tasks.CheckFileSystemCaseSensitive”
>   in Windows Powershell but the same build works in VS Powershell

**Since** you built extension project successfully in vs powershell, I think you put a wrong MSBuild version in **PATH** system environment variables.

**Instead**, you should use `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\xxx\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe`.

**Solution**

**1)** check the **PATH** and remove the previous wrong MSBuild path.

**2)** then input `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\xxx\MSBuild\Current\Bin` in **PATH**, restart Windows Powershell to build again.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, although it seemed like an intermittent issue and got fixed on its own today.

Answer (score 1):

When you are running it **from VS integrated PowerShell it uses correct version of MSBuild** but may not find latest one when running from Windows PowerShell.

If you want to use the Latest available MSBuild on any machine; Visual Studio(VS2017 and above) comes with utility called [vswhere](https://github.com/microsoft/vswhere) which can be used to find out latest MSBuild version

**You can manually update the PATH in environment variable** or write a PS script to **find the latest MSBuild version using below code snippet**

```
$vsWherePath = ${Env:ProgramFiles(x86)} + '\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe'
$detectedMSBuildPath = & $vsWherePath -latest -requires Microsoft.Component.MSBuild -find MSBuild\**\Bin\MSBuild.exe;

Write-Host $detectedMSBuildPath
& $detectedMSBuildPath -version #Command to execute msbuild
```

This way, even if your MSBuild version is updated; it will always find and use latest MSBuild on machine.